# PlayerController (Unity/C#). Условия запуска анимаций по 8-ми направлениям. Ошибка "не все пути возвращают значение

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблематика: пишу код для запуска Спрайт-анимаций в зависимости от направления движения по X и Y. Перечислил все состояния (x>0 y>0, x>0 y<0, x<0 y<0, x<0 y>0, x=0 y<0, x=0 y>0, x>0 y=0 x<0 y=0).
Ошибка:

> "TopDownController.GetSpriteDirection()": не все пути возвращают
> значение.

Заранее извиняюсь за стилистику. Полный нуб. Код писал по уроку.

Код:

```
List<Sprite> GetSpriteDirection()
{
    List<Sprite> selectedSprites = null;
    if (direction.y > 0) // north east
    {
        if (direction.x > 0)
        {
            selectedSprites = nESprites;
        }
    }
    else if (direction.y > 0) // north west
    {
        if (direction.x < 0)
        {
            selectedSprites = nWSprites;
        }
        else if (direction.y < 0) // south east
        {
            if (direction.x > 0)
            {
                selectedSprites = sESprites;
            }
            else if (direction.y < 0) // south west
            {
                if (direction.x < 0)
                {
                    selectedSprites = sWSprites;
                }
            }
            else if (direction.y < 0) // south
            {
                if (direction.x == 0)
                {
                    selectedSprites = sSprites;
                }
            }
            else if (direction.y > 0) // north
            {
                if (direction.x == 0)
                {
                    selectedSprites = nSprites;
                }
            }
            else if (direction.y == 0) // east
            {
                if (direction.x > 0)
                {
                    selectedSprites = eSprites;
                }
            }
            else if (direction.y == 0) // west
            {
                if (direction.x < 0)
                {
                    selectedSprites = wSprites;
                }
            }
            return selectedSprites;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто return на 2 строки ниже переместите

Answer (score 1):

У тебя столько `if`, что ты сам запутался. Первое же условие ничего не возвращает, если х не больше нуля. Вся эта пизанская башня вообще не нужна, дело решается в две строчки и конкатенацией.

```
public string GetCompasVector (Vector2 vector)
{
    string ver = vector.y > 0 ? "n" : 
       vector.y < 0 ? "s" : "";
    string hor = vector.x > 0 ? "e" : 
       vector.x < 0 ? "w" : "";
    return ver + hor;
}
```

```
string spriteName = GetCompasVector(direction) + "Sprite";
```

Comment: Можно ещё так `string ver = vector.y switch { > 0 => "n", < 0 => "s", _ => "" };` как вариант. Правда не знаю, Unity кушает C# 9 или нет.

Comment: @aepot, от синтаксического сахара тоже толстеют) Человек новичок, скорее всего даже с тернарным операторам не знаком, взрывать ему мозг передовым синтаксисом не стоит) И да, да... тернарник тоже сахар, не бей)))

Answer (score 0):

Каждая ветвь в методе `GetSpriteDirection` должна возвращать `List<Sprite>`, например, `selectedSprites`. У вас есть первое условие `direction.y > 0` и, соответственно, две ветви: когда это условие верно, и когда нет. Обе эти ветви должны возвращать какое-то значение списка. А у вас значение возвращается только в одной из последующих подветвей блока `else`.

Проще всего в таком случае написать оператор `return` один раз в самом конце метода, а в каждой из ветвей только изменять соответствующим образом возвращаемый список. Или же, если ветвей немного и они очевидны, то использовать несколько операторов `return` (но в этом конкретном случае это не так, ибо ветвей много)